# how to convert this array to array with index and value

Tags: php

How can I convert this array The value of the new array index array is the first and the second value is an array as the value for the index.
For example, in the new array is indexed hadaf and its value buy
And similarly for the others.
example hadaf=>buy
array first:

```
array (size=2)
'name' => string 'type' (length=4)
'value' => string 'ویلایی' (length=12)
1 =>
array (size=2)
'name' => string 'hadaf' (length=5)
'value' => string 'buy' (length=8)
2 =>
array (size=2)
'name' => string 'name' (length=4)
'value' => string 'ali' (length=8)
3 =>
array (size=2)
'name' => string 'mobile' (length=6)
'value' => string '444444444' (length=9)
4 =>
array (size=2)
'name' => string 'address' (length=7)
'value' => string 'masshad' (length=8)
```

Comment: Show some of your array, and what you expect the new array to look like, don't simply describe it in vague and ambiguous words

Comment: My best guess, based on your description: `$tmpArray = array_chunk($oldArray, 2); $newArray = array_combine($tmpArray[0], $tmpArray[1]);`

Comment: A more detailed explanation of the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `array_column` if PHP > **5.5** like as

```
print_r(array_column($your_array,'value','name'));
```

Use `array_walk`

```
$result = [];
array_walk($your_array,function($v) use (&$result){
    $result[$v['name']] = $v['value'];
});
```

Comment: undefined function array_column() php is >5.5 . Another method is not available?

Comment: @mahdieh, [This simple library provides functionality for array_column() to versions of PHP earlier than 5.5. It mimics the functionality of the built-in function in every way.](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column)